# Property is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to post to the multiline `TextBox`. The data is coming from a different method in a separate class.

```
class converter
{
    public static void convert(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f)
    {
        //... some job done now post this data to winforms
        Form1.textBox1 = "File Copied" + "  " + 
                         DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") +
                         Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

I'm not able to access `textBox1` from this class. It says:

> Form1.textBox1' is inaccessible due to its protection level
>   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property Form1.textBox1'

Comment: Are you sure your text box is named textbox1 and not textBox1?

It may also be useful to know that you need to set the content correctly, e.g like this:

Form1.textBox1.Text = "MyText";

Comment: Yes, you are right my mistake. But now the error is : Form1.textBox1 is inaccessible due to it's protection level.

Comment: shouldn't it be Form1.textbox1.text not only Form1.textbox1

Comment: @harhar: I tried that it's giving me the error as in my edit above

Comment: Look at my answer below, you need to invoke the textBox.

Form1.textBox1.Text.Invoke(new Action(delegate(){textBox1.Text="MyText"})); or Form1.Invoke(new Action(delegate(){textBox1.Text = "MyText"}));

Comment: @user726720 see my example below, it works for me.

Comment: @Adam K Dean - I suspect OP is also trying to change it across threads, meaning that method won't work without invoking.

Comment: If that is the case then your solution will work better, but given that he can't seem to figure out protection levels, I don't think he would be playing with multiple threading.

Answer (score 1):

`Form1` is probably the name of your form's type, not the name of a `Form1` instance variable.
Since `convert` is probably called from one of the instance methods in Form1, you could move

to the caller instead of introducing a dependency in convert

```
convert.convert(...);
textbox1 = "File Copied" + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") +
           Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: I have start/stop buttons. So if I say start the control transfers to the a different class with my methods to do some job it never really transfers back until I say stop. So Now after pressing start and when the job is activated I want the data to be written to multiline text box in the forms class

Answer (score 1):

You can change the TextBox to public, pass an instance of Form1 but these approaches violates  the  basic tenants of encapsulation, the class converter should not know anything of Form1 and its controls.

A better approach is for the class converter to define an event that will be called by the class if a caller desires to be notified and update something internal (the textBox) after the converter class has done its job.

```
class converter
{
   public delegate void OnCopyComplete(string file);
   public event OnCopyComplete CopyComplete;
   public static void convert(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f)
   {
       //... some job done now NOTIFY the caller 
       if(CopyComplete != null) CopyComplete(source.ToString());
   }
}
```

And in Form1 instance

```
// tell to the converter class that this class wants to be notified when the work is finished
converter.CopyComplete += new converter.OnCopyComplete(UpdateMyLabels);
converter.convert(....);


public void UpdateMyLabels(string file)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "File Copied" + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning encapsulation. The class method should return the results to the form.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Form1` and make `TextBox1` Public in control properties (hit F4)
and change the property `modifiers` from **Friend** to **Public**

After that. You can do the following:

```
 Form1 form1 = new Form1;
 form1.TextBox1.Text = "File Copied" + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: What if the form is already instantiated? This solution does not work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is have a field in the form:

```
public static TextBox textBox;
```

and set that to the textbox in the form_load:

```
this.textBox = textBox1;
```

and then in the method above, call it like:

```
Form1.textBox.Text = ...
```

Full working example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverflowWin
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static TextBox textBox;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox = textBox1;

            TestClass.StaticMethod();
        }
    }

    public static class TestClass
    {
        public static void StaticMethod()
        {
            Form1.textBox.Text = "works";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed use the existing instance of the form:

```
var form = Form.ActiveForm as Form1;

if (form != null)
{
     form.textBox1.Text = "File Copied" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") + Environment.NewLine";
}
```

You should actually use events, which is more proper design, but above should work.

Comment: textbox1 inaccessible due to it's protection level

Comment: @user726720 This is the default property for controls, and can be solved by going into Design-View for the Form that contains the specified Control, then changing the Control's Modifiers property to Public or Internal.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will be needed:

```
Form1.Invoke(new Action(delegate(){ textBox1.Text = "MyText"}));
```

Apologies if the code is incorrect, but it's close enough to get you started with google.

If the above doesn't work this might:

```
Form1.textBox1.Text.Invoke(new Action(delegate(){textBox1.Text="MyText"}));
```

I can't remember exactly how it is done.

Maybe this:

```
Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    Form1.textBox1.Text = "MyString";
}));
```

Comment: It says the an object reference is required for the non-staic field

Answer (score 0):

Set property: Modifier = Public

Comment: This will not work unless he has the form variables reference. He only has the type, Form1, not form1.

Answer (score 0):

Why not include the form as parameter of your static method like:

```
class converter
{
 public static void convert(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f, Form frm)
{
//... some job done now post this data to winforms
frm.textbox1 = "File Copied" + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

But make sure that your Texbox is public in your Form1

```
        public static TextBox textBox1;
```

**Edit**:

So, if you don't want a public Textbox then you have to create in your Form1 a public and static property and just pass the value of the textbox there before passing the form like:

```
 public static String fromTextBox { get; set; }
```

Then additionally in your Form1 you save the value of your textbox to fromTextBox property:

```
 fromTextBox = textBox1.Text;
```

So, you could now access it like this:

```
 class converter
 {
  public static void convert(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f, Form frm)
  {
//... some job done now post this data to winforms
 frm.fromTextBox = "File Copied" + "  " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") + Environment.NewLine;
 }
```

Comment: Thats the whole point I don't want to enable public on the textbox, as stated by Steve it's not a good idea

Comment: @user726720 you could probably create a separate public and static property to store the textbox. See my edit above.