# c# Delegates and events to send text from class to form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**Duplicate Question:** [Property is inaccessible due to its protection level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730290/property-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level/16730355?noredirect=1#comment24092282_16730355)

I want to send a string from the class to the forms textbox using delegates and Events as in the duplicate question above. As I'm new to this topic (Delegates and Events) I'm not able to set this up. Here is what I have done:

```
class Converter
{
    public delegate void SendText( Converter c, EventArgs e);
    public event SendText RaiseEvent;

    public static void WatchFile()
    {
        // watcher is initialized (code is not show)  
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(convert);
    }

    public static void convert(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f)
    {
        //do something then 
        if (RaiseEvent != null) 
        { 
            // Raise event and send text to controls 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error message:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Ansi_UTF_8_converter.Converter.RaiseEvent'

Can you tell me if the above is the right way of doing it.

Comment: why upvote? any reasons?

Comment: Please, don't create new delegate types for event handlers. Use `EventHandler` or `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` instead.

Comment: @Dennis: Can you please demonstrate that. I would love to learn this technique

Comment: @user726720: instead of `public delegate void SendText( Converter c, EventArgs e); public event SendText RaiseEvent;` use `public event EventHandler RaiseEvent;`. Also, note, that guidelines recommend to name events as some happened action ("Changed", "Clicked", "Checked", "Received", etc). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the static of the function to class method:

```
public void convert(object source, FileSystemEventArgs f)
{
  //do something then 
  if (RaiseEvent != null) { ... }
}
```

or change the event static:

```
public static event SendText RaiseEvent;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is static but your event isn't static as the error message tells you.

Maybe this helps you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx

The point is your function does not work on an object of your class but you use an object of your class inside your function which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your event should be static in this context of ussage

```
public static event SendText RaiseEvent;
```